# Displaying Last Year (Fiscal) Data based on Current Year Date Filter

Tags: calendar, powerbi, dax

I want to state in advance that I am almost entirely new to Power BI, DAX and associated languages.

I have created a date calendar which possesses, among other things the following columns:

```
DATE, YEAR_WEEK(Fiscal), ly_DATE(Fiscal) ly_YEAR_WEEK(Fiscal)
```

as defined by the following:

`DATE`: e.g. 01/25/2014. The granularity of the dates is one day. In this case, this is the 27th day of the fiscal year 2014, which is also given a column with data.

`YEAR_WEEK(Fiscal)`: e.g. 2014W04, a value given to 7 sequential dates which defines the fiscal year and corresponding week of said year.

`ly_DATE(Fiscal)`: e.g. 1/26/2013; the corresponding (27th) fiscal date of the previous year, 2013.

`ly_YEAR_WEEK(Fiscal)`: e.g. 2013W04, the corresponding fiscal last year and week of the given date, which is also defined by ly_DATE(Fiscal).

My data is set up as follows (example):

[image: Data Table]

And I will be setting up my data matrix as follows, barring any advice given in regarding this endeavor:

[image: Data Matrix Set Up]

Where the Calendar Dates have been linked to the Ending Date of the data table, and the Company Code and Company Name are for this purpose irrelevant.

What I want to do is, for any given sum of `Amount` in a specific week, to display to its immediate left (ideally without that small gap which is displayed every time different column values are displayed in a Power BI bar graph, so far as I am aware) the sum of data in the equivalent previous year fiscal week.

I am confident that this must be possible given how the data is set up (and indeed, is very simple to display in Excel) but as I am a beginner in Power BI I can't make heads or tails of it.